# How to ByPass Local Proxy to connect to 3rd party VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy

the company I work for has put a lot of restrictions in our computer system. we cannot browse a number of sites and here is why. 
the Systems are connected via LAN cables and the IT guys have put proxy of their own 
[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJHuw.png)

Now, If i disable this proxy option (Image above), the internet stops working for some reason. if i try to install a VPN, the internet stops working (I can understand that the VPN overrides the proxy settings and hence the internet stops responding.

I was wondering, is there a workaround to bypass this proxy and actually be able to use a third party VPN? May be I can use another port to connect to?

Comment: If you have to use a VPN to work, contact your IT dept, they will work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. I cannot trespass the local proxy setup by the IT Department, I can instead connect to another proxy.

I tried [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html) and It worked for me. It basically connects to another proxy and lets user browse the content without any restriction